# How to move mmapped pages between files on Linux?

Tags: linux

I have a few files, each `open`ed and `mmap`ed individually.

I want to concatenate them into one larger file.

Ideally I would create the file, `ftruncate` it to the correct size, and "somehow" move the pages of smaller files to the correct offset. However I didn't find any system calls to move pages from file to file on Linux.

Right now, my solution is simply `write` the data, but this is wasteful because I don't actually need two copies.

Is there a way to "move" `mmap`ed pages between files on Linux?

Or is there a way to concatenate them using file descriptors?

Comment: Just `memcpy()` into the new `mmap()`ed file? Or maybe use `sendfile()`?

Comment: @Shawn `memcpy` is equivalent to `write` to me because I have access to both the mapping and the fd. `sendfile` looks promising but the man page doesn't indicate if it's zero-copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by the comments `sendfile` would transfer file contents between two file descriptors, however, this is not a "move" operation, i.e. after the operation, both the source and destination file descriptors are still valid.

Depending the file system in use, kernel may optimize `sendfile` as a reflink operation so that it's truly "zero-copy", however, if the file system doesn't support reflink, then there will be a copy at the page cache level. This is saves half the copy overhead than read/write because it doesn't have to copy between userspace and kernel space.

So even though `sendfile` is not the ideal answer for me, it's better than read/write.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to copy data from one file to another, then the fact they are memory-mapped doesn't help you, because the data will end written to the disk anyway.

So my suggestion would be:

If what you need is: `file1 + file2 => file3` then

```
1. rename(2) file1 => file3
2. copy file2 data => end of file3 using mmap facility and memory operations.
```

Comment: My situation is, after the process, neither file1 nor file2 need to exist. I'm trying to take advantage of this fact and optimize away the copying.

Comment: You can eliminate the copying to and from userspace using `splice()`, but the filesystem data are going to be copied at some point (and you'll need to have enough space for `file3` and `file1` during the copy).